# what types of files used for streaming in apache spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I want to know what are the file types used to load data in **apache Spark**,        example (CSV,txt etc)

Comment: By the way, the Hadoop tag isn't really necessary since Spark can work without HDFS & YARN

Answer (score 0):

`fileStream` can accept any file type as long as you can provide input format class that can convert it to records. To be useful input should be splitable and easy to parse without reading a whole file but it is not must have as long as you can accept performance penalty.